# Render partial with link_to in Google maps info window

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to render a partial by clicking a title within an info window of the Google map on my site.

I am creating the info window with this code:

`var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content, disableAutoPan: true});`

This is what I'm passing as `content`:

`"#{escape_javascript(render 'user/map_infowindow_multiple')}"`

Here's my link within the `map_infowindow_multiple` partial that I am passing to `content`:

`= link_to user.name, multi_user_map_user_path(user), remote: true`

Controller action:

```
def multi_user_map 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'multi_user_map.js.haml' }
  end
end
```

Route:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :multi_user_map
  end
end
```

Within the `multi_user_map.js` file I have just got an alert for now, I just want to see that *something* happens when I click the link in the info window.

This is successfully creating the info window with the content that I want, however when I click the link nothing happens.  I think it might be an issue with my route, but I'm not sure.

I'm new to Rails and Stack Overflow, sorry if I'm missing something here.

Comment: I would start by checking your routes at http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes and manually enter the URL you are expecting into your browser, see if it outputs the right JS. Then use Chrome devtools networks tab to see if that's the URL being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check the route by running "rake routes" command. After clicking the button check the console in the browser( Inspect element in browser). Usually javascript related errors will be shown there. And I hope you have written a function to handle the remote request generated by the button click.